# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars diff += X_values * (y_values - ((X_values * m) + b))

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
import math, copy 

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("D:/Code/Vscode/test1/honeyproduction (3).csv")
prod_per_year = df.groupby('year').totalprod.mean().reset_index()

X = prod_per_year["year"].values.reshape(-1,)
y = prod_per_year["totalprod"].values.reshape(-1,)
prod_per_year.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1))
y_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))


def get_gradient_at_b(X, y, b, m):
    N = len(X)
    diff = 0
    for i in range(N):
        X_values = X[i]
        y_values = y[i]
        diff += y_values - ((X_values * m) + b)
    b_gradient = -(2/N) * diff
    return b_gradient    

def get_gradient_at_m(X, y, b, m):
    N = len(X)
    diff = 0
    for i in range(N):
        X_values = X[i]
        y_values = y[i]
        diff += X_values * (y_values - ((X_values * m) + b))
    m_gradient = -(2/N) * diff
    return m_gradient

def step_gradient(X, y, learning_rate, b_current, m_current):
    b_gradient = get_gradient_at_b(X, y, b_current, m_current)
    m_gradient = get_gradient_at_m(X, y, b_current, m_current)
    b = b_current - (b_gradient * learning_rate)
    m = m_current - (m_gradient * learning_rate)
    return [b, m]

def gradient_descent(X, y, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    b = 0
    m = 0
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        b, m = step_gradient(X, y, learning_rate, b, m)
    return b, m

b, m = gradient_descent(X, y, 0.004, 1000)

y_pred_scaled = [(x * m + b) for x in X_scaled]
y_pred_scaled = np.array(y_pred_scaled) 
y_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_scaled.reshape(-1,1))
X = X.tolist()
y = y.tolist()
print(X)
print(np.shape(X))
print(y)
print(y_pred)
print(np.shape(y_pred))

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, y_pred, color='red')
plt.show()
```

I tried to scale X,y, try to fix any missing value, and after print out the y_pred is still NaN,

I also got runtime errors invalid value encountered in double_scalars
m = m_current - (m_gradient * learning_rate)
so rn I'm try to decreasing the learning rate or increasing the number of iterations to see if that improves the performance of the model,

can any1 check on my code please, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

```html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def get_gradients(X, y, b, m):
    N = len(X)
    b_gradient = -(2/N) * np.sum(y - (m*X + b))
    m_gradient = -(2/N) * np.sum(X * (y - (m*X + b)))
    return b_gradient, m_gradient

def gradient_descent(X, y, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    b = 0
    m = 0
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        b_gradient, m_gradient = get_gradients(X, y, b, m)
        b -= learning_rate * b_gradient
        m -= learning_rate * m_gradient
    return b, m

df = pd.read_csv("D:/Code/Vscode/test1/honeyproduction (3).csv")
prod_per_year = df.groupby('year').totalprod.mean().reset_index()
prod_per_year.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

X = prod_per_year["year"].values
y = prod_per_year["totalprod"].values

# Normalize the input data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1, 1))
y_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))

b, m = gradient_descent(X_scaled, y_scaled, learning_rate=0.1, num_iterations=1000)

# Inverse transform the predicted data to obtain the original scale
y_pred_scaled = m * X_scaled + b
y_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_scaled)

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, y_pred,)
plt.show()
```

HERE IS THE MODIFIED CODE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).